# Do multiple Eclipse-based IDEs conflict with each other?

Tags: ide, eclipse

Based on a [previous question, where I asked about IDEs to support development in multiple languages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118954/how-do-i-develop-in-more-languages-with-less-ides), Eclipse and Eclipse-based IDEs were mentioned in some of the answers. If I were to use these tools, would there be conflicts between them, or can they run side by side smoothly? Is it also possible to run different Eclipse instances with seperate plugins installed in each one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They can run side-by-side without any problems, at least in my experiences. I've run CodeWarrior and Eclipse together, and I'm running Eclipse and IBM ClearQuest Client open at the same time right now.

Each Eclipse-based application is a unique application, with its own settings, plugins, configuration files stored in its directory. You can install and configure them independently of each other without any problems, which includes plugins.

Comment: They will create a directory here: C:\Users\<username>\.eclipse and the both will consult and update files there. There MIGHT be some cross reading between both. Maybe they could run smoothly side-by-side but they may crash each other if some files becomes incompatible.

Answer (score 4):

They run side by side smoothly. You can even have different instances of classic Eclipse and they would run side by side smoothly.

Eclipse stores all of its configuration in its installation directory, so no conflicts, and all of the workspace settings in the workspace directory so you can have as many workspaces as you need.

update: And yes you can run as many instances with separate plugins as you need. All plugin configuration is stored in the instance's installation directory.

Answer (score 3):

They may run side by side, as long as each has its own workspace and set of projects. When you try to mix them, running multiple instances on the same source directories, things can quickly go very wrong in very nasty ways (especially if you try to run them at the same time on that source tree).